# Would a csv file uploaded for a code be affected by VBA code

Tags: python, excel, vba, pandas, csv

I am currently working on quite a large sized spreadsheet and so changing the values on it would be quite tedious to do. I was thinking of using VBA excel in order to make things easier in terms of changing a range of cells. 
Would doing this affect the uploaded csv file on Python? 
Would I need to change my code? The matrix is about a 180x6 size

```
import itertools
import copy
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1=pd.read_csv(r"U:\\user\nodes_fixed.csv")
print(df1)

#print(df1.isnull().values.any())

df2=pd.read_csv(r"U:\\user\edge_list_3_fixed.csv")
df2= df2.dropna()
print(df2)
```

Comment: If you're doing read only, inherently it will do nothing to change the document outside of some very strange cases. I would say that the above code would not change it, but why not just make a copy of the CSV?

Comment: @AndrewMcGrail so if I add some VBA coding to the excel spreadsheet and convert it to a csv the vba coding would not affect this conversion?

Comment: When you convert to a csv the code will be thrown away, The csv file would only contain the contents of the active sheet

Comment: @HarassedDad is right. Excel CSVs do NOT contain anything other than cell values from a sheet.